# USB persistent + live boot

Tags: boot, usb, virtualbox, persistence

I would like to install Ubuntu on my 128 GB with persistent data.

If possible I would like to boot it within virtual box so I can access it from any windows computer.

Is it possible?

Comment: Your 128 GB USB what? 128GB ipod? USB based pendrive? USB based external HDD? USB based external SSD? .. I am missing a word.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this can help?

[How to create bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Also you can just download the [ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=latest) and then install the OS using virtual box or VMPlayer, no need of loading from USB sticks.